# Discrete normal distribution numpy array

Tags: numpy, statistics

How do I create a normal distribution like this with numpy?

```
norm = np.array([0.06136, 0.24477, 0.38774, 0.24477, 0.06136])
print(np.sum(norm)) // output: 0.99999999999
```

I am assuming there should be some sort of function, like

```
np.f(deviation, mean, n_elements)
```

What am I to look for?

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy.random.normal(). See manual here, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html.

For example (as mentioned in the manual),

```
mu, sigma = 0, 0.1 # mean and standard deviation
s = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000)
```

This will give you a vector with 1000 elements, each drawn from a normal distribution with mean 0 and sigma 0.1.

Comment: OP's intentions are very unclear. guessing can work but why bother guessing when OP hasn't clarified yet?